# Java heap space issue while creating Apache poi Workbook

Tags: csv, apache-poi, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to convert a large xlsx sheet to csv using the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345696/convert-xlsx-to-csv-with-apache-poi-api) and [here](https://gist.github.com/tranminhan/991207) . But it is throwing the below error on line

`XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));`

Error

```
Caught throwable Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77)
```

Is there any efficient way to convert large xlsx sheet to csv without increasing heap memory?

My code is as below-

```
try 
    {   
        // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
       // XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
        XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));

        for(int i=0;i<wBook.getNumberOfSheets();i++) 
        {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wBook.getSheetAt(i);
            fileName = convertedFileLocation + sheet.getSheetName() + ".csv";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            //System.out.println(wBook.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName());

            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                    data.append("\"" + cell.getStringCellValue() + "\",\r\n");  
                }
            }
            fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
         }
        wBook.close();
     }
```

Edited---

I am using XSSF as suggested by @axel and @gagravarr in the comment and using the class method as below. Though it is creating the converted.csv file the csv file is empty. Any idea what I am doing wrong

```
private boolean convertToCSV2(File file)
{
    try {
        OPCPackage p = OPCPackage.open(file.getPath());

        String convertedFileLocation = siteConfigService.getProperty(CONVERTEDFOLDER);
        String convertedFileName = convertedFileLocation+"converted.csv";
        PrintStream pout=new PrintStream(convertedFileName);  
        XLSX2CSV xlsToCSV = new XLSX2CSV(p, pout, -1);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please read [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) and then try [example XLSX2CSV.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java).

Comment: Hi Axel, I have gone through this but there are few imports in this example which are not there in the jar I have in my project. e.g import import org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.SAXHelper;

Comment: Make sure you're using a new enough version of Apache POI then! Latest stable is recommended

Comment: Thanks. I changed to newer version and able to compile the code however there is another issue. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Gagravarr- can you please suggest what I am doing wrong in calling the method. Also how can I read different sheets in xlsx and create different csv file for each?

Comment: Your code lacks `xlsToCSV.process();`.